# If I suspect corruption of BITS and/or ReadyBoost in Windows 8.1, what specific files can I scan with sfc to try and rectify the issue?

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, bsod, readyboost

I have had numerous BSOD restarts over the last month, usually when I am transferring files from a USB device to another USB device. Corresponding errors in event viewer seem to indicate a problem with BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service) and/or ReadyBoost. I also am going to run a RAM test and tests on all hard drives. I am going to run SFC and DISM, but I would also like to start with a sfc scan of specific files involved with BITS and ReadyBoost. Is there a location where I can find the file(s) associated with the BITS service and/or other Windows services?

Comment: More likely there is an issue with the flash drive being used fro ReadyBoost than the drivers... flash has finite usage life, and ReadyBoost makes intensive use of it. A general *SFC /scannow* should catch any file issue, though it might take an hour to complete.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Why didn’t you wait to ask this question after you had the required information for us?  You can use windbg to analyze your mini dump files to determine the cause of your crashes.  Several existing questions have answers that go into detail on how to do exactly that.  What part of the process are you stuck on?

Comment: Yeah but it does not seem to matter what USB drives are plugged in. It does this with ALL USB drives regardless.

Comment: Being aware of possible overheat issues with the USB 3 controller on my motherboard, I replaced the motherboard with the next revision of the same board which uses a new USB 3 controller and updated the drivers. But the issue has persisted.

Comment: I also redid the thermal compound on the northbridge and southdridge heatsinks, using high quality Arctic Cooling MX-4.

Comment: I am not asking for assistance in troubleshooting my issue. Don't overanlyze it. The question is straightforward, I am just looking for the files involved in the Background Intelligent Transfer Service. A google search has not revealed the answer. OK different question: where does Windows store the services at? Like is there a BITS file somewhere?

Comment: You want us to provide you a list of files connected to that service.  Your asking for a list with a couple dozen files? That is unrealistic ask.  No, there isn’t a “BITS” file.  if you suspect the service you can disable it.  The list of background services that require the service to work for them to work is numerous though

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik the weird part is that i believe ReadyBoost is part of the SuperFetch service in Windows 8.1 (tell me if I am wrong about that) and I have that disabled, so ReadyBoost shouldn't be doing anything. However I am seeing errors in event viewer from around the time of the crash(es) that reference "rdyboost: 4"

Comment: Well where can I find that list? The TechNet documentation on BITS is very comprehensive, I have read through dozens of pages, but I have yet to find anything about the actual file locations.

Comment: Yeah I know, I really DON'T want to disable BITS. If SFC or DISM do not work, I probably will need a clean install and that is not something I am looking forward to, I have hundreds, maybe even thousands, of programs that would need to be reinstalled.

Comment: Instead of reinstalling Windows which likely won’t actually solve your problem, you should use windbg, and analyze the crash to find the cause of the crash.  You can then ask how to solve your problem.

Comment: But there is no crash to analyze. Windows is not registering a BSOD. There are just some corresponding to errors to go by. EDIT: OK there is a single 0x07E crash but an analysis only reveals that the error is in BITS but that does not necessarily tell me that BITS is corrupted, it could be an error on a hard drive or a RAM error. Another 0x07E from a few days ago is from ReadyBoost. But I have never seen an actual BSOD screen, the computer just reboots and no error message comes up on boot either.